# Как в данной процедуре прописать exeption для игнорирования ошибки

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace PROCEDURE EVENT_LOG_CLEANER
```

вот ошибка

```
ORA-08102: index key not found, obj# 159375, file 5, block 2522200 (2)
ORA-06512: at "STRONGHOLD.EVENT_LOG_CLEANER", line 22
ORA-06512: at line 2
```

Comment: Ну ихним же ж по белому пишут - индекс повреждён. Перестрой его или пересоздай.

Comment: Да это так ,  но как определить какой именно индекс перестроить,  там их несколько?

Comment: А смысл? перестройте все, хуже точно не станет. См. напр. тут: https://logic.edchen.org/how-to-resolve-ora-08102-index-key-not-found/

Comment: Смысл в том ,  что база весит 480гб  ,  а таблица имеет 22 индекса.  Перестройка займет очень много времени.

Comment: Ну попробуй запросами к одной таблице определить конкретную таблицу, в которой порушился индекс и перестроить только её индексы... ничего лучше предложить не могу.

Comment: Как я уже писал выше ,  таблица известна, но у нее 22 индекса . И перестраивание всех индексов займет много времени.  Нет ли какого нибудь способа определить какой именно индекс сломан по той ошибке которая есть ?

Comment: Да понятия не имею... но что-то меня сильно сомневает в наличии такой возможности - Оракл вообще славен невменяемостью диагностики.

Comment: Ну да бог с ним Oracle ,  вопрос был следующий,  как в процедуру добавить exeption для обработки возникшей ошибки ?

Comment: Ну как-то вот так: [Handling PL/SQL Errors](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B10501_01/appdev.920/a96624/07_errs.htm)